# Django 1.8 - Can access var in base.html, but same variable empty when I extend into another page (articlePage.html)

Tags: python, html, django, url

I have a news article style site I'm building to learn Django.  Anyways I've gotten everything working until I got to the sidebar.  With the sidebar I have an issue.  When I'm on the 'base.html' or the 'article.html' page the **latest_article_list** works and shows up.  When I try to extend 'base.html' to 'articlePage.html' **latest_article_list** is an empty variable.

My question is how do I get it so that I can access **latest_article_list** in the 'articlePage.html', I have no problem accessing it in 'base.html' nor in 'article.html' *which extends base.html*.  articlePage.html *ALSO extends base.html* but as I said, it won't work there.

[image: Sidebar on article.html(my index) working as expected displaying 4 most recently added articles and a thumbnail]
*Sidebar on article.html(my index) working as expected displaying 4 most recently added articles and a thumbnail*

[image: Sidebar on articlePage.html(page for each individual article) not displaying any recent articles, just my error msg]
*Sidebar on articlePage.html(page for each individual article) not displaying any recent articles, just my error msg*

Does it have to do with the fact my article url's are dynamic and not static?   I'm completely lost, so any help would be great.

I've provided a link to my repository.
The 'pip' installations I have for this project are: *Django 1.8, Pillow 2.8.1 and VirtualEnv 12.1.1*

https://github.com/kevinIN3D/articleTestProject

Comment: Sounds like you `latest_article_list ` is not being applied into the context for your `articlePage.html`.  Check the view and make sure the variable is being applied in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you declare block 'sidebarBlock' in base.html but you don't fill it with something neither in index.html nor in articlePage.html. It works in index.html because you send variable with your view. You cannot take any variables from your base.html. You should provide these in your ArticleView.
It should look like this:

```
class ArticleView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'articles/articlePage.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.latest_article_list = Article.objects.filter(
            article_pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-article_pub_date')[:4]
        return Article.objects.filter(article_pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['latest_article_list'] = self.latest_article_list
        return context
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks alot @pythad.  I'd tried to pass the context data in that class before but I kept getting errors so I figured that was the wrong approach, I guess not.  Trust my gut and just screw around with it until it works I guess.

Comment: How would I go about **not** including the current article in the list?  
would it be something like 
'context['latest_article_list'] = self.latest_article_list - Article[Article.pk]' ? Or am I way off in my thinking.  I don't know if that syntax is proper but my logic is get the latest_list then remove the Article[current id]

Comment: @KevinLeegsma You can use exclude(**kwargs). I believe your query should look like Article.objects.exclude(article__pk=pk).filter(
            article_pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-article_pub_date')[:4]
In your url you need to capture pk as 'pk', DetailView needs this.
More here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters)

Comment: sorry for my Django newness.  What is meant by capture 'pk' in my URL?  I understand the chaining of querysets to refine search options.  But I don't understand the former, the capturing pk.  Do you mean something like?  
**url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ArticleView.as_view(paginate_by=3, pk = views.Article.pk), name='showArticle'),**

Comment: @Kevin yes, you can catch values with regex, you even don't need to name your pattern, but not about this now. You can read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups. **url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ArticleView.as_view(paginate_by=3), name='showArticle'),** this is what you need, after this you can access pk in your view. (You don't need to grab it somewhere in your view, DetailView does this for you).